# EF 4.3 Beta 1 on Optional Relationship the Cascade Delete leaves Orphans

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, one-to-many, cascading-deletes

Is this odd?

When deleting relationships of one to many, if a the relationship is optional and you delete the parent object the rest will remain orphan and it does not cascade delete.

```
    var album = new Album
                {
                    Name = "Test Album",
                    Description = "Test Album Description",
                    Images = new Collection<Image>
                    {
                        new Image {
                            Name = "Image 1",
                            Description = "Image 1 Description"
                        },
                        new Image {
                            Name = "Image 2",
                            Description = "Image 2Description"
                        },
                    }
                };

            albumRepository.Add(album);
            albumRepository.UnitOfWork.Commit();
```

Under the Image Entity I got the AlbumId as Nullable since some images can be orphaned.

And then I call.

```
albumRepository.Delete(toRemove);
albumRepository.UnitOfWork.Commit();
```

The Album gets deleted but the images that where once related are Orphaned and their AlbumId is removed from the row.

Comment: Take a look at [How do you ensure Cascade Delete is enabled ...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471374/how-do-you-ensure-cascade-delete-is-enabled-on-a-table-relationship-in-ef-code-f)

Comment: Awesome! That was the key thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did it.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Image>()
.HasOptional(d => d.Album)
.WithMany(d => d.Images)
.WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```