# How to delete an entity which has many to many relation with other tables?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to Entity Framework. Is it possible to delete an entity from a table directly instead of going and clearing all the many to many connection with other tables?

```
var artist = _artistDetailsRep.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ArtistID == id);

_artistDetailsRep.Delete(artist);
_artistDetailsRep.SaveChanges();
```

This code complains because the artist has many to many connections (constraints) to artistTypes. So  what works is below

```
 artist.ArtistTypes.Clear();
_artistDetailsRep.Delete(artist);
_artistDetailsRep.SaveChanges();
```

I need to explicitly clear all the artisttypes and then delete the artist. Is there a way of doing this automatically? Basically it should delete all the connection by itself instead me going and saying delete those constraints?

May be you can suggest a better approach to these scenarios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can let SQL Server do this for you by using [Cascading Deletes](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2743/using-delete-cascade-option-for-foreign-keys/). Entity Framework also has support for this by using the `WillCascaseOnDelete()` method in the Fluent API, see [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#CascadeDelete) for more information. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471374/how-do-you-ensure-cascade-delete-is-enabled-on-a-table-relationship-in-ef-code-f) also might help you.

Please keep in mind that cascading deletes are pretty dangerous though, one mistake in your code might wipe a complete table in your database.

Comment: so, this is not enabled by default?

Comment: @J.W. no, I hope not. Usually when this isn't configured EF throws exceptions about reference constraint violation.