# Removing child entity not deleting in database entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two entities "YogaSpace" and "YogaSpaceImage" I'm deleting an image and trying to get the row removed, instead it just nulls out the reference to the YogaSpace entity.

Here are my entities.

```
public class YogaSpace
{
    public int YogaSpaceId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<YogaSpaceImage> Images { get; set; }
}

public class YogaSpaceImage
{
    public int YogaSpaceImageId { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageThumbnail { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public int Ordering { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the method that deleted one image from the db.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RemoveImage(string id, string imageId)
    {
        YogaSpace yogaSpace = yogaSpaceRepository.Find(Convert.ToInt16(id));
        YogaSpaceImage image = yogaSpace.Images.FirstOrDefault(si => si.YogaSpaceImageId == Convert.ToInt16(imageId));
        yogaSpace.Images.Remove(image);

        yogaSpaceRepository.InsertOrUpdate(yogaSpace);
        yogaSpaceRepository.Save();

        return Json("removed");
    }
```

here is what's inside my repo to insertorupdate()

```
public void InsertOrUpdate(YogaSpace yogaSpace)
    {
        if (yogaSpace.YogaSpaceId == default(int))
        {
            context.Entry(yogaSpace).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
        }
        else
        {
            context.Entry(yogaSpace).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
```

and here is the result. you can see the row doesn't get deleted, null gets put into the reference column. I don't have a repo for YogaSpaceImage entity, only YogaSpace so trying to use it so I don't have to create another repo.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark the entity as deleted.

```
yogaSpace.Images.Remove(image);
context.YogaSpaceImages.Remove(image)
```

your other option is to mark you mapping with `.WillCascadeOnDelete()`

E.g.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder mb)
{

    mb.Entity<YogaSpace>().HasMany(p => p.Images )
        .WithRequired()
        .HasForeignKey(c => c.YogaSpaceImageId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete();

}
```

The other option is to have a ForeignKey on the `YogaSpaceImage` back to the `YogaSpace` (if it is a mapping of 1 `YogaSpace` - 0-many `Image`) and mark the `YogaSpaceImage.YogaSpace` foreign key required. Therefore whenever EF tried to remove the foreign key, it will automatically delete the Image.

```
public class YogaSpaceImage
{
    public int YogaSpaceImageId { get; set; }        
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageThumbnail { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public int Ordering { get; set; }

    public int YogaSpaceId { get; set; }
    [Required] <-- This will delete the image, if removed from parent
    public virtual YogaSpace YogaSpace { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: is there any way to use .willcascadeondelete in the RemoveImage() code? or a way to use data annotations? isn't this method above for fluent api?

Comment: Yes, see the first part, you can manually remove that image from the `YogaSpaceImages` `DbSet`. This will delete the row on SaveChanges()

Comment: I tried adding this onModelCreating code but now I get a error when starting up that relates to the multiplicity of yogaspace images

Comment: no this is a one to many relationship. Is this syntax correct for a one-to-many rel?

Comment: If thats the case you will have to go to the database, make sure that the image is not referenced by any other YogaSpace, and then remove it.

Comment: Or remove it and catch the foreign key constraint exception.

Comment: if you want it to be 1 to many then edit your `YogaSpaceImage` by adding the `[Required]YogaSpaceId` and `virtual YogaSpace`

Comment: When you mark it the navigation property as required, EF will automatically cascade the delete, as an `Image` is required to have a `YogaSpace`, if EF sees that it would cause it to not have one, it will delete it.

Comment: let me give this a try. hold one sec

Comment: no, this doesn't work. Are you sure you have the syntax correct for a one-to-many rel?

Comment: I'm looking here http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: did you add the required attribute?

Comment: yes I tried this. It doesn't work. I'm not sure I've seen a required attribute on a virtual call before on entities, can you provide any links or tutorials that show this?

Comment: try putting it on YogaSpaceId

Comment: or making the navigation property non virtual

Comment: im downloading SSMS as i reformatted my pc recently, will take hours, so going sleep, will check back in the morning

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471374/how-do-you-ensure-cascade-delete-is-enabled-on-a-table-relationship-in-ef-code-f

Comment: not sure if this makes a difference but I'm not deleting the yogaspace and all child entities, I'm just deleting the image (child entity)

Comment: by deleting the image, you mean removing it from YogaSpace

Comment: yes, but actually it would be deleting it from yogaspaceimage.