# c# Entity Framework 6 on delete cascade one to many

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a question. How can I delete one field and all other one to many relations?

```
Field has
 - List<Years>
Years has
- List<Crop>
Crop has
- List<Pesticide>
- List<Fertilizer>
```

if i use

```
db.Fields.Remove(field);
```

it will only delete the field not all related records

How can remove all years if remove a field or if i remove a year all crops will be removed

**UPDATE:**

I have tried:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Entity.Field>()
             .HasOptional(c => c.Years)
             .WithMany(); 

 Query IQueryable<Entity.Field> query = ctx.Set<Entity.Field>() 
         .Include(c => c.Years); 

 var list = query.ToList();
```

but I get this error:

> Error: MetadataException: The declared type of navigation property FieldManager.Context.Field.Years is not compatible with the result of the specified navigation

Comment: ...what language?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you ensure Cascade Delete is enabled on a table relationship in EF Code first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471374/how-do-you-ensure-cascade-delete-is-enabled-on-a-table-relationship-in-ef-code-f)

Comment: c# entity framework 6

Comment: @Stefan i saw this question but it won't work for me.

Here a link to my code: https://hastebin.com/asuwoseriw.scala

Comment: Hi, I updated your question to reflect your comment. I am missing the essential: `.WillCascadeOnDelete(true);` part. Keep in mind, that if you make your year `Required`, cascade on delete is enabled by default.

Comment: @Stefan i didn't set the Required property. Thanks a lot. Now it works fine.